# How to extract number, including all text before the number, from a string

Tags: r, regex

I have a list of addresses, containing (1) house number and (2) building name. I wish to separate the strings into two columns. The tricky part is some of the house numbers contain character, e.g. "221B Baker Street".

Example below:

```
add <- c("5 Ark Royal House" , 
     "22A Blington Garden Lincoln Street", 
     "Flat 19 PICTON HOUSE" , 
     "2-3 Royal Albert Court" , 
     "Room 1 Grand Hall", 
     "No 17 The Dell Alpha House")
```

The ideal results look like below:

```
aim <- data.frame("No"=as.character(c("5", "22A", "Flat 19", "2-3", "Room 1", "No 17")), 
              "Building" = as.character(c("Ark Royal House", 
                                          "Blington Garden Lincoln Street" , 
                                          "PICTON HOUSE", 
                                          "Royal Albert Court" , 
                                          "Grand Hall" , 
                                          "The Dell Alpha House")))
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `stringr`:

```
library(stringr)
lst <- str_match_all(add, "^(\\D*\\d[-\\w]*)\\s+(.+)")

(aim <- setNames(as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, lst)),
                c("all", "No", "Building")))
```

Or in vanilla R:

```
pattern <- "^(\\D*\\d[-\\w]*)\\s+(.+)"
lst <- regmatches(add, regexec(pattern, add, perl = T))
(aim <- setNames(as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, lst)),
                 c("all", "No", "Building")))
```

---

Both will yield

```
                                 all      No                       Building
1                  5 Ark Royal House       5                Ark Royal House
2 22A Blington Garden Lincoln Street     22A Blington Garden Lincoln Street
3               Flat 19 PICTON HOUSE Flat 19                   PICTON HOUSE
4             2-3 Royal Albert Court     2-3             Royal Albert Court
5                  Room 1 Grand Hall  Room 1                     Grand Hall
6         No 17 The Dell Alpha House   No 17           The Dell Alpha House
```

See [**a demo for the expression**](https://regex101.com/r/bASfGN/1) on regex101.com.

Answer (score 1):

Base approach, finds the gap in between the number and the name, replaces it with a hopefully neutral character (in this case `_`, but it could be anything you know to not be in any addresses), then splits on that character.

It makes the assumption that the last 'word' of containing a number is the end of the 'No' component. If that's not true for all your addresses (it is for all your test cases), this won't work.

```r
add <- c("5 Ark Royal House" , 
  "22A Blington Garden Lincoln Street", 
  "Flat 19 PICTON HOUSE" , 
  "2-3 Royal Albert Court" , 
  "Room 1 Grand Hall", 
  "No 17 The Dell Alpha House")

split_add <- strsplit(gsub('([0-9\\-]+[0-9A-z]*) ', '\\1_', add), split='_')

aim <- setNames(as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, split_add)),
  c('No', 'Building'))

aim
#>        No                       Building
#> 1       5                Ark Royal House
#> 2     22A Blington Garden Lincoln Street
#> 3 Flat 19                   PICTON HOUSE
#> 4     2-3             Royal Albert Court
#> 5  Room 1                     Grand Hall
#> 6   No 17           The Dell Alpha House
```

<sup>Created on 2019-02-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>